# Blur only objects after a certain distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, blur

I work at a 3d game in Unity URP and i want to make an "Inspect element console" where the 3d objects come in front of the camera and the player can rotate them. So for this i search for a shader graph that will blur my screen and that's worked very nice .
The main problem is that the shader blur all my objects , it doesn't matter where on my screen the 3d object is. Someone can please help me ? Or maybe some another options , what can i use instead of a graph shader?

I tryed to mask the Ui image that holds my shader material but i have this error : "Material Blur doesn't have _Stencil property".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the depth of field effect from the post processing stack. Documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@17.0/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html), depending on which version you are using.